# Autoprefixer doesnt work inside Gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

Guys I added Autoprefixer plugin inside my gulp file EVERYTHING works fine but the CSS wont spit out autoprefixed css.I will be happy to get help.Below is my gulpfile.js :

```js
// require gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// require other packages
var concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

// scripts task
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
});

// styles task
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
});

// browser sync
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['styles'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: ''
        },
        notify: false
    });
    gulp.watch("./src/sass/*.scss", ['scss']);
    gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// watch task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

// image minification
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  var imgSrc = './src/img/**/*',
      imgDst = './dist/img';

  gulp.src(imgSrc)
    .pipe(changed(imgDst))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDst));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles', 'browser-sync', 'imagemin', 'watch']);
```

I hope you guys will help me through this :)

Answer (score 0):

The `config` passed to `autoprefixer` is wrong. It should be

```
.pipe(autoprefix({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    }))
```

Reference: [gulp-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer#usage)

Comment: made the changes as suggested but still this doesn't Autoprefix yet :(

Answer (score 0):

**Try init autoprefixer after create css.**

Autoprefixer makes changes in css. It is not working on sass files.

---

UPDATE

**Before you copy new gulpfile.js, add in Your console cmd on project path**

```
npm install gulp-postcss autoprefixer es6-promise --save-dev
```

**Then copy new gulpfile.js configuration with autoprefixer**

```
// require gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// require other packages
var concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
   // autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'); -- comment this line

// scripts task
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
});

// styles task
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/sass/*.scss')
  //  .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions')) -- comment this line
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
});

// =========================================
// Start - Add packages / new configurations

require('es6-promise').polyfill();
var postcss      = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

gulp.task('autoprefixer', function () {

    return gulp.src(
          ['.dist/css/*.css', '!.dist/css/*.min.css']
      )
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.dist/css/'));
});

// =========================================
// End new lines

// browser sync
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['styles'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: ''
        },
        notify: false
    });
    gulp.watch("./src/sass/*.scss", ['scss']);
    gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// watch task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

// image minification
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  var imgSrc = './src/img/**/*',
      imgDst = './dist/img';

  gulp.src(imgSrc)
    .pipe(changed(imgDst))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDst));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles', 'browser-sync', 'imagemin', 'watch']);
```

**After that try write in Your cmd console**

```
gulp autoprefixer
```

---

Regards :)